# Is Magento is right platform for beauty product website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, ecommerce-tracking, features

Today there are many eCommerce platforms are available such as Shopify, BigCommerce, WooCommerce but I want to know about how to Magento is best to compare to other E-Commerce platforms. Last Week I have seen one blog of **Top 5 Best eCommerce Platforms for small business** - this blog provides great information but I want to know about Magento eCommerce platform, please give me answer about benefit and features of Magento.

Answer (score 2):

So Wordpress is known for best CMS then Magento,as I think, is known for eCommerce.This platform was born to be an e-commerce. It is flexible(you can do almost anything according to the client’s needs). The huge plus of that platform is open source,so anyone can use it to his/her advantage.
The best thing about Magento for ecommerce is that it allows you to perform multiple tasks at the same time.
So to say shortly,if you want to sell something then of course, Magento is the best.But if you want to have a simple website for advertisement or blog,then it is better to use Wordpress :)

Answer (score 1):

**Magento features and benefits**

Magento is a powerful open source platform that is designed perfectly to complement your ecommerce website, in fact it has been built exclusively to offer a robust, scalable and user-friendly ecommerce service. The accessibility of Magento makes it a winning solution for many businesses, but it also comes with a host of other benefits.

If you’re unsure about Magento and whether or not you should be using it for your ecommerce store, read this first.

1. Magento Websites Start From The Ground Up
   For any business owner looking to get into ecommerce, you are able to start from the ground and work your way up with Magento. It’s free to start with the Community Edition whereby a complete website can be created from scratch, with full ecommerce capabilities. All websites built with Magento are responsive for optimal user experience, meaning they can render to fit any device size for your customers. There are also a number of “out-of-the-box” features that come standard with the setup as well as extensions that can be added to customize the ecommerce store to perfection.
2. Magento Is All About Ecommerce
   While many other content management systems will have a plugin that offers ecommerce capabilities, Magento is built exclusively for that function. This is what makes it such a popular choice for online shops as it has been built to offer all dimensions of the business in an online store space. Everything from transaction records and reporting to loyalty, payment gateways and complete inventories has been included, making it an all-in-one solution for the discerning ecommerce business owner.
3. Magento Is Scalable And Customizable
   As your ecommerce business expands, so too can your website, especially when you’re working with Magento. It’s completely scalable, meaning it can be adapted to suit additional products, more inventory, higher volumes of traffic, multiple payment gateways and more. Provided you are running on the latest version of Magento, you’ll have access to all the latest features, updates and benefits.

In addition to having a platform that can grow with your business, you can also custom-build the entire website or aspects of it using extensions and Magento development services. It’s almost a case of “if you can dream it, you can build it” as the sky is the limit with the features you can add onto your Magento ecommerce website.

When it comes to extensions, there is an incredible Magento community that are willing to share the work they’ve done in order to simplify the lives of others. You can purchase existing extensions to build features on your Magento website, or you can get an expert Magento developer to build it for you if it doesn’t yet exist. 9 times out of 10, you can purchase exactly what you need and have it built seamlessly into your website in no time.

Magento 1.x For Ecommerce Businesses
Many businesses will vouch for the simpler approach when it comes to the earlier versions of Magento up until Magento 2.0. Magento has always been a well organized system and it’s easy to get started with it if you have basic PHP knowledge, but if you’re going to build an ecommerce website with Magento, it’s best to use Magento 2.0, the latest version, in order to take full advantage of what it can do.

Magento 2.0 For Ecommerce Businesses
Magento 2.0 offers all the latest tweaks and updates that have been carefully programmed and planned in order to make the experience offered to users that much more beneficial. It also offers a higher level of security than previous versions, as any attempts to hack various segments of ecommerce stores on prior versions will now have been thwarted with the latest security updates. As with anything, it’s always a case of the newer models overriding older ones, as they are essentially new and improved.

Even so, whichever version of Magento you choose to work on, you will always get the extensive functionality and capabilities that come standard with the platform.

I hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it's great help to my eCommerce Website Developers..